# Auto suggest on gridview when typing on textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Can anyone help me on how can I do auto suggest on gridview when typing on textbox. Almost 1 week I seek for the solution. I already check my select statement, it connect to my database. And now I do not know why that coding is not function. Please somebody help me. This is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;




namespace EmployeeVerification
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    //Connection String
    string cs = "Server=..;User Id=sa;Password=..;Database=..";
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlDataAdapter adapt;
    DataTable dt;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //table to show in gridview
        con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select [name], [empno], [workno] from [GMT].[dbo].[m_employee] where not [recsts] = 'R' order by empno", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();

        //make the textbox read only
        textBoxICPass.ReadOnly = true;
        textBoxPassport.ReadOnly = true;
        textBoxDept.ReadOnly = true;
        textBoxSection.ReadOnly = true;

        pictureBox1.Visible = false;

        dataGridView1.Visible = false;

        textBoxEmplNo.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
        textBoxWorkNo.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
        textBoxName.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;

        DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
        column.Width = 300;


    }



    //auto suggest on gridview when typing on textbox
    private void textBoxName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select [name], [empno], [workno] from m_employee where name like '%" + textBoxName.Text + "%' and not [recsts] = 'R' order by empno", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();

        if (textBoxName.Text != null)
        {

            dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        }


    }

    private void labelEmplNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBoxEmplNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBoxWorkNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void labelTitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttonSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void textBoxICPass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }


    //show the row value in textbox
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxName.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        textBoxEmplNo.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        textBoxWorkNo.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        textBoxICPass.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        textBoxPassport.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        textBoxDept.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        textBoxSection.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();

        dataGridView1.Visible = false;
    }

    //clear all the textbox fields after click 
    private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control crt in this.Controls)
        {
            if (crt.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                crt.Text = "";
                pictureBox1.Visible = false;


        }
        dataGridView1.Visible = false;
    }

    private void labelICPass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBoxWorkNo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (textBoxWorkNo.Text != "")
            {
                //Do something
                string selectSql = "select name, empno, icnum, passport, deptno, section from m_employee where workno=@workno";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workno", textBoxWorkNo.Text);


                bool isDataFound = false;

                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        while (read.Read())
                        {
                            isDataFound = true;

                            textBoxEmplNo.Text = (read["empno"].ToString());
                            textBoxName.Text = (read["name"].ToString());
                            textBoxICPass.Text = (read["icnum"].ToString());
                            textBoxPassport.Text = (read["passport"].ToString());
                            textBoxDept.Text = (read["deptno"].ToString());
                            textBoxSection.Text = (read["section"].ToString());


                        }


                    }

                     if(!isDataFound)
                     {
                         textBoxEmplNo.Text = "";
                         textBoxWorkNo.Text = "";
                         textBoxName.Text = "";



                         // Display message here that no values found
                         MessageBox.Show("No Result Found");
                     }
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                textBoxEmplNo.Text = "";
                textBoxName.Text = "";

            }

            string imgFilePath = @"C:\Users\hamizah\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\EV\photo\" + textBoxWorkNo.Text + ".jpg";
            if (File.Exists(imgFilePath))
            {
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imgFilePath);
            }
            else
            {
                // Display message that No such image found
               // MessageBox.Show("No Image Found");
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\hamizah\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\EV\photo\No-image-found.jpg");
            }

        }

    }

    private void textBoxEmplNo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (textBoxEmplNo.Text != "")
            {


                string selectSql = "select name, workno, icnum, passport, deptno, section from m_employee where empno=@empno";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmplNo.Text);

                bool isDataFound = false;

                try
                {

                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (read.Read())
                        {
                            isDataFound = true;

                            textBoxWorkNo.Text = (read["workno"].ToString());
                            textBoxName.Text = (read["name"].ToString());
                            textBoxICPass.Text = (read["icnum"].ToString());
                            textBoxPassport.Text = (read["passport"].ToString());
                            textBoxDept.Text = (read["deptno"].ToString());
                            textBoxSection.Text = (read["section"].ToString());

                        }
                    }

                    if(!isDataFound)
                    {
                        textBoxEmplNo.Text = "";
                        textBoxWorkNo.Text = "";
                        textBoxName.Text = "";

                        // Display message here that no values found
                        MessageBox.Show("No Result Found");

                    }
                }
                finally
                {


                    con.Close();
                }

            }

            else
            {
                textBoxWorkNo.Text = "";
                textBoxName.Text = "";
            }

            string imgFilePath = @"C:\Users\hamizah\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\EV\photo\" + textBoxEmplNo.Text + ".jpg";
            if(File.Exists(imgFilePath))
                {
                    pictureBox1.Visible = true;      
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imgFilePath);
                }
            else
                {
                      // Display message that No such image found
                        MessageBox.Show("No Image Found");
                }

        }


    }





}
}
```

Comment: does the gathering of data work in the `Form_Load` event?

Comment: _that coding is not function_ What is not working? Doesn't it show the datagridview? doesn't it show any row? does it shows empty rows? You can try setting the `dataGridView1` datasource to null and refreshing it (`dataGridView1.Refresh()`) before setting again the `DataSource`

Comment: @Pikoh the datagridview is not appears when I'm typing.

Comment: @MongZhu it work. The problem now is, the gridview is not appears when i typing in textbox.

Comment: does the GridView disappear? or just not updating with the expected results?

Comment: why do you divert from the syntax that you used in the `Load` event : `[GMT].[dbo].[m_employee]` ??

Comment: @MongZhu The gridview is not appears when I typing in textbox. I want the gridview autosuggest while i'm typing in textbox.

Comment: why do you make it invisible?? `dataGridView1.Visible = true;` ? and why do you wonder that it does not appear when you type text, because then you make the condition `if (textBoxName.Text != null)` true...

Comment: @MongZhu because I want to search datagridview by using textbox

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes within your code:

1. You are setting `dataGridView1.Visible = false;` at various places within your code, remove all of them for instance, just for the sake of testing, you can add them later based on your requirements.
2. Remove this part of query `where not [recsts] = 'R' order by empno"` because for now it is useless and I don't understand why you are using this, you can apply  filters later and also `select ... from m_employee` instead of [dbo]... etc..
3. Instead of `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();` get data from selected row like this: `textBoxName.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["name"].Value.ToString();` Because in future, if you increase/decrease the number of columns or re-arrange the order of getting data, it will not effect.

I've tested your code with these modifications and it works perfectly.

Comment: @M Adeel Khalid thanks for your respond. But it still not work for me :(

Comment: Its weird if it doesn't work for you because I've tested your code with my temp db and it works.

Comment: @M Adeel Khalid. Thanks for your respond. It already work after I do key press event for name textbox. :)

Comment: It means you didn't register an event before use.